# Error cannot read length of undefined for an array retrieved using firebase

Tags: javascript, html, css, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to loop through the array of comments so that I can display each item in the array on the webpage which was pushed into firebase. But when I loop through the array I get an error - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined.

```
const dbRef = firebase.database().ref();
const usersRef = dbRef.child('users').orderByChild("post_likes");
readPostData(); 
function readPostData() {

    const postListUI = document.getElementById("post-list");
    usersRef.on("value", snap => {
        postListUI.innerHTML = ""
        snap.forEach(childSnap => {
            let key = childSnap.key,
                value = childSnap.val()
                
            let $li = document.createElement("li");
            // edit icon
            let editIconUI = document.createElement("span");
            editIconUI.class = "edit-post";
            editIconUI.innerHTML = " ✎";

            // delete icon
            let deleteIconUI = document.createElement("span");
            deleteIconUI.class = "delete-post";
            deleteIconUI.innerHTML = " ☓";

            let commentIconUI = document.createElement("span");
            commentIconUI.class = "edit-post";
            commentIconUI.innerHTML = " +";

            let likeIconUI = document.createElement("span");
            likeIconUI.class = "like-post";
            likeIconUI.innerHTML = `&#128420;`;
            getPostAnswersArray = value.post_answers;
            console.log(getPostAnswersArray)
            
            for(i=0; i<=getPostAnswersArray.length-1; i++){
                console.log(getPostAnswersArray[i])
            }
                $li.innerHTML = `
            <p id="post_title">${value.post_title}
            <span id="post_date"><small>on ${value.post_date}</small></span>
            <span id="post_author">
            <small class="post_author">${value.post_author}</small>
            </span>
            </p>
            <hr>
            <p id="post_content">${value.post_content}</p>
            <hr>
            <p id="comments">Comments<span id="num_likes"><small>${value.post_likes} likes</small></span></p>
            <div id="showAns"><small>${getPostAnswersArray}<small></div>

            `;
            var author = value.post_author;
            var current_author = firebase.auth().currentUser.email;
            $li.append(likeIconUI);
            $li.append(commentIconUI);
            $li.append(editIconUI);
            $li.append(deleteIconUI);
            postListUI.prepend($li);
        });
    })
}
```

The error comes when I try to console.log(getPostAnswersArray[i]). What could be the possible solution to this?

Comment: `getPostAnswersArray` where did you initialize it?

Comment: It is actually not defined... Where did you define it?

Comment: Sorry, I actually deleted that line while posting the question by mistake.